# Ошибка при работе с select.value

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять причину ошибки. Буду благодарен за объяснение. В предыдущем смоем учебном коде, построенном по такому же принципу, данная строка не вызывает никаких проблем.

js:

```
var select = document.getElementById('siteColor');
var html = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');

select.addEventListener('change', changeSite);

function changeSite() {
    var choice = select.value;
    switch (choise) { /* проблема в этой строке, независимо от того, что я хочу сделать с переменной choise (main.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: choise is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.changeSite) */
    case 'White':
        update('White','Black');
        break;
    case 'Black':
        update('Black','Purple');
        break;
        ....
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <p class='first'>Live output</p>
        <p>Select theme: <select id='siteColor' name='siteColor'>
            <option></option>
            <option value='White'>White</option>
            <option value='Black'>Black</option>
            <option value='Purple'>Purple</option>
            <option value='Purple'>Yellow</option>
            <option value='Psychedelic'>Psychedelic</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p class='site'>This is my website</p>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts\main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ну так choice и choise это разные слова

Comment: Спасибо. Перерыл кучу информации по данному вопросу, а про элементарную ошибку в записи забыл проверить. Решились все проблемы с другими вариациями кода. Буду держать этот случай в голове. Вопрос закрыт.